# Clip path внутри круга?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, svg

Можно ли создать внутренний контур clip path круга, чтобы контур clip path эффективно прорезал отверстие через div в центре, а не только показывал центр?

Все div должны быть показаны за исключением отверстия, вырезанного в центре, чтобы создать что-то вроде этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хотел бы использовать clip path или что-то подобное, чтобы я мог иметь  (изображения и контент) за div, и clip path будет использоваться для выявления этого. Таким образом, div (синий div из моего jsfiddle) исчезнет из центра, используя `transition`, чтобы показать содержимое за ним.

```css
div {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50px at center);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Clip path inset circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37000558/7394871) от участника  [@Rafty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4167229/rafty).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/37000558/7394871

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сделать такое в `clip-path` простыми фигурами (polygon, circle и т.п.) не получиться. Но, есть же ещё `url()` с SVG. И тут открывается возможность для реализации задуманного. Главное - творчески подойти. Вся магия в форме `<path>` (осторожно! "вырвиглаз"):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(40deg, #080 10%, #fa0 12%, #c50 18%);
  background-size: 100%;
  animation: bg 1s infinite ease-in-out alternate;
}

.svg { position: absolute; height: 0; width: 0; }

.fon {
  height: 300px; width: 400px;
  clip-path: url(#my-clip-path);
  animation: rot 6s infinite linear;
}

.clipped {
  height: 225px; width: 300px;
  background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/600x600?summer);
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 2s ease;
  animation: rot 6s infinite linear reverse;
}
.clipped:hover {
  height: 600px; width: 800px;
  opacity: .5;
  transition: 1.5s ease;
}

@keyframes rot { to { transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes bg { to { background-size: 300%; } }
```

```html
<svg class="svg">
  <clipPath id="my-clip-path" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"><path d="M0.5,0 L0.5,0.333 A0.125,0.167,0,1,1,0.5,0.667 A0.125,0.167,0,1,1,0.5,0.333 L0.5,0 L0,0 L0,1 L1,1 L1,0"></path></clipPath>
</svg>
<div class="fon">
  <div class="clipped"></div>
</div>
```

*В виду того, что это "свободный перевод", похоже, что также "свободно" написанного вопроса, то сей ответ является тоже свободным, так как не совсем ясна суть.*

Comment: Юра, ты совершенно правильно понял суть вопроса. Автору нужно было, чтобы в верхнем  div clip-path прорезал отверстие, сквозь, которое были бы виден нижний слой. Но clip-path не вырезает, а обрезает по определению. Для вырезания отверстия нужна маска

Comment: @Alexandr_TT: ну и славненько. Я всё никак не займусь плотнее SVG, там поле непаханое фишек всяких. Хотя, CSS всё больше расширяет возможности (вот пример - [conic-gradients](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-images-4/#conic-gradients) Поддержка у [всех](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-conic-gradients), кроме огнелиса - он из под флага)

Answer (score 6):

Не знаю почему этого ответа еще не было, можно сделать дырку в `clip-path` вот так:

```js
let precision = 64;
let radius = 25;
let c = [...Array(precision)].map((_, i) => {
  let a = -i/(precision-1)*Math.PI*2;
  let x = Math.cos(a)*radius + 50;
  let y = Math.sin(a)*radius + 50;
  return `${x}% ${y}%`
})

document.querySelector('div').style.clipPath = 
 `polygon(100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, ${c.join(',')})`;
```

```css
body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200/200)
}

div {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Я сгенерировал это кодом, однако можно просто вставить результирующий стиль:

```css
div {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200/200)
}
```

```html
<div style="clip-path: polygon(100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0px 100%, 0px 0px, 100% 0px, 100% 50%, 75% 50%, 74.8758% 47.5108%, 74.5043% 45.0463%, 73.8893% 42.6311%, 73.0369% 40.2891%, 71.9555% 38.0437%, 70.656% 35.917%, 69.1511% 33.9303%, 67.4559% 32.1033%, 65.5872% 30.4542%, 63.5637% 28.9994%, 61.4053% 27.7532%, 59.1335% 26.7282%, 56.771% 25.9344%, 54.3412% 25.3798%, 51.8683% 25.0699%, 49.3767% 25.0078%, 46.8914% 25.194%, 44.437% 25.6268%, 42.0378% 26.3018%, 39.7178% 27.2124%, 37.5% 28.3494%, 35.4064% 29.7015%, 33.4579% 31.2555%, 31.6737% 32.9957%, 30.0717% 34.9049%, 28.6677% 36.9641%, 27.4758% 39.1529%, 26.5077% 41.4495%, 25.7731% 43.8311%, 25.2792% 46.2739%, 25.0311% 48.7539%, 25.0311% 51.2461%, 25.2792% 53.7261%, 25.7731% 56.1689%, 26.5077% 58.5505%, 27.4758% 60.8471%, 28.6677% 63.0359%, 30.0717% 65.0951%, 31.6737% 67.0043%, 33.4579% 68.7445%, 35.4064% 70.2985%, 37.5% 71.6506%, 39.7178% 72.7876%, 42.0378% 73.6982%, 44.437% 74.3732%, 46.8914% 74.806%, 49.3767% 74.9922%, 51.8683% 74.9301%, 54.3412% 74.6202%, 56.771% 74.0656%, 59.1335% 73.2718%, 61.4053% 72.2468%, 63.5637% 71.0006%, 65.5872% 69.5458%, 67.4559% 67.8967%, 69.1511% 66.0697%, 70.656% 64.083%, 71.9555% 61.9563%, 73.0369% 59.7109%, 73.8893% 57.3689%, 74.5043% 54.9537%, 74.8758% 52.4892%, 75% 50%);"></div>
```

Comment: Класс! Сам не силён в вычислениях, потому всегда восхищаюсь подобным. Только не ленитесь фон на бэк кидать, чтобы видеть прозрачные участки сразу.

Comment: @UModeL это же всего лишь окружность, если уменьшить кол-во точек будут еще  другие простые фигуры =)

Answer (score 5):

### Решение SVG mask

В качестве маски использована окружность, у которой анимируется радиус.

*Анимация начнется посл клика*

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 600 600" >  
     <defs>
         <!-- Многоцветный радиальный градиент -->
     <radialGradient id="grad" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0">

        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
       <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
       <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#503969" />
        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
        <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#503969" />  
        <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
       <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
        <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
        <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#503969" />
        <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
     </radialGradient>
         <!-- Маска -->
     <mask id="msk1" > 
            <rect  width="100%" height="100%"  fill="black" /> 
             
       <circle cx="300" cy="300"  r="0" fill="white" >
            <!-- Анимация маски прорезающей изображение дракончика и показывающее радиальный градиент  -->
         <animate attributeName="r" begin="svg1.click" dur="8s" values="0;300;300;0;0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="3" />
        </circle>
     </mask>
     </defs> 
               <!-- Фоновое изображение радиальный градиент   -->
      <circle  cx="300" cy="300"  r="300"  fill="url(#grad)"  />  
                 
          <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kywq.png" x="-140" y="-60" mask="url(#msk1)" width="800" height="780" />  

</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

Я не думаю, что вы можете добиться этого с помощью `clip-path`, но вы, безусловно, можете вырезать отверстие в div, используя фоновые изображения с радиальным градиентом. Это хорошо поддерживается браузерами.

Примечание. Этот подход (и box-shadow) будет работать только тогда, когда элемент, закрывающий содержимое ниже, имеет цветную заливку. Если вместо песочно-коричневого цвета поверх должно быть другое изображение, тогда эти подходы не будут работать, потому что они на самом деле не прорезают отверстие, а просто имитируют этот эффект.

```css
.div-with-hole {
  height: 100vh;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, transparent 25%, sandybrown 25.5%);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
.div-with-hole:hover {
  background-size: 400% 400%; /* should be 100% * (100 / transparent % of radial gradient */
}
body {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/800/nature/1);
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='div-with-hole'></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37001058/7394871) от участника  [@Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry).</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Вы также можете сделать это с помощью `box-shadow` на `:after` псевдоэлементе

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url('http://planetcompas.com/live/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/2015-01-Beautiful-Planet-And-Space-4-Cool-Wallpapers-HD.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
div:after {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 300px lightblue;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
div:hover:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37001333/7394871) от участника  [@Nenad Vracar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4620771/nenad-vracar).</sub>